# Custom Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 entities:

- Institution
- Branch
- Address

Institution & Branch will have many Addresses, so in order to not create two child models for storing the address of each entity, I want to create a pivot table which will have these columns as primary key: entity_id, address_id, entity_name. With this approach I will store the relationship of all addresses for Institution and Branch.

This is my code in entities_addresses pivot table

```
Schema::create('entities_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('address_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('model_name', 50);
        $table->primary(['entity_id','address_id','model_name']);
```

Next, in Address Model I have the following code:

```
public function institutions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Institution::class, 'entities_addresses', 'entity_id', 'address_id');
    }
```

Next, in Institution model I have the following code

```
public function buildings()

    {
        return $this->hasMany(Building::class);
    }
```

I believe I need to add somewhere else which is the "custom" relationship, beacuse now I'm recieving this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'addresses.institution_id'

So, my questions are:

1. Where do I have to specify the custom relationship?
2. It's a better approach to create an intermidate model?
3. I will have to customize the use to be attach and detach methods? In which place I willhave to do it?

Regards

Comment: Eloquent  already has Polymorphic relationships.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks @devon definitly that can be the Solution. Regarda